# How ## operator in macro works?

Tags: c, macros

I was studying some macro operations, and I got this Code and I was unable to figure out how this code is actually working and generates the output? and is there any (i-+) operator that exists or not?
Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define p(a,b) a##b 
#define call(x) #x 
int main()
{ 
   do{ int i=14,j=3; 
   printf("%d",p(i-+,+j)); 
}while(*(call(625)+3)); 
return 0; 
}
```

Output is 10.
It will be very helpful if you explain it with some examples.

Comment: Do you know what `##` does?

Comment: It is used for concating two elements which will be passed in macro definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `##` in the macro is the concatenation operator, it glues its operands together. So after the preprocessor is done, that expression will be

```
i-++j
```

which of course just means `i - (++j)`, i.e. `14 - 4` which of course is `10`.

Comment: O thank you, now I get it , I think that this ## operator is just used for concating so + - will may not work here.